# "Warning: session_start() ..." after changing apache document root

Tags: php, apache, session, httpd.conf

I have changed the following two lines in httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "/xampp/htdocs">
```

New lines are -

```
DocumentRoot "D:/PHP"
<Directory "D:/PHP">
```

Now I am getting error

> Warning: session_start(): open(\xampp\tmp\sess_876q6mj308epe9635v680ov0ba, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory

and

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: \xampp\tmp)

What else i need to do now?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

Comment: @AbraCadaver Got the point. Thanks.

Comment: Apache on Windows... why ?